# Hide or change + and - buttons for ToggleItem textboxes in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

Hi have setup some textbox as "ToggleItems" in SSRS, in order to hide/show some columns ("Show Actual" and so on...).

Everything works, the only annoying fact is that SSRS always adds a + and - signs to the textbox (which would be correct if used in a drill-down scenario).
Is it possible to disable the + and - signs, or to change them to something else? or to mimic some sort of "buttons" ?

[image: report screenshot]

Comment: Without having the text box be a link to reopen the report with the relevant report part's visibility set by parameters (Or simply having the "Which part to show" as a parameter instead of clickable textbox), I do not think this is possible.

Comment: I have tested and google a lot, it seems this is the only available behaviour.
It could be implemented as you say, with actions and parameter but it will require re-loading the report instead of simply hiding/unhiding the columns...

Comment: As you suggested I tried a textbox set to a "Go to Report" action, to reopen the same report setting a boolean parameter to its opposite, and the visibility of items set to this parameters. It works, but needs to refetch data each time, and the query that runs in background is already quite long...

Answer (score 1):

**The Real Answer:**
In current versions of reporting services, there is no way around this.  Only the + or - button is clickable for a toggleitem.  Therefore there is no way to cover/hide the button as nothing would be clickable.  I agree that you should be able to change this.

Comment: Quite impractical, but could be a solution nonetheless. Only question: how can I set multiple "ToggleItems" to toggle visibility for a report Item? Only one can be set, AFAIK....

Comment: I was able to set each of the textbox toggleitems to one report item [Textbox17]

Comment: actually it should be the opposite...[Textbox17]  would need to have all 4 other textBoxes ad ToggleItems...

Comment: I see now.  I didn't have a full understanding of the toggleitem... I am researching a way to use multiple toggle items for one report item now.  I can edit my question to remove the second half.  Sadly, the answer to your original question is that you can't change the image.